# Restrict document access to particular user in alfresco

Tags: alfresco

Is there any way by which I can show particular documents to particular users only ? In alfresco, all users from a site can see all the documents. I want to show the particular document to some users only. I am using alfresco community edition. Can somebody help me ??

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A site is just a folder. The site folder contains "container" folders for things like the document library, wiki, data lists, etc. You can set permissions on these folders just like you can any folder in Alfresco. Similarly, documents can have their permissions set individually.

The confusion arises because when you are using Share in the context of a particular site, the permissions settings don't offer granular settings. But if you navigate to your site through the "Repository" view (see the link at the top of the page), you can have full control over the permissions.

Suppose we have a site called test-site and a folder called test in that site's document library that contains a document, testdoc.pdf. You should be able to:

1. Click the "Repository" link at the top of the page.
2. Click the "Sites" folder.
3. Click the "test-site" folder.
4. Click the "documentLibrary" folder.
5. Click the "test" folder.
6. Click testdoc.pdf to open its details page.
7. Click "Manage Permissions".

By default, objects inherit the permissions of their parent. So testdoc.pdf has the permissions of its parent folder. If you want to remove all permissions and set explicit, "local" permissions on testdoc.pdf...

1. Click "Inherit Permissions" to turn off inheritance.
2. Click "Add User or Group" to add specific users or groups with the access level you want them to have.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for reply. This is exactly what I want. Now I am trying to achieve the same through java using PermissionService class. But this is not giving the desired result as mentioned above. So can you please suggest me some better option ??

Comment: You definitely can do the exact same thing as what I've outlined above using the PermissionService. If you've tried but are having trouble, create a new question with the specific problem, code snippet, and error message and I or someone else will take a look.

Comment: I have done it using PermissionService service itself. Thanks again.